# Install Ros1-Bridge on Foxy is Failing

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

**Edit**: text version of the error log:

```
root@7e18fbc1e12c:/# apt install ros-foxy-ros1-bridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-foxy-ros1-bridge : Depends: ros-noetic-actionlib-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-catkin but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-common-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-gazebo-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-geometry-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-nav-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-rosbash but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-roscpp but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-roscpp-tutorials but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-roslaunch but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-rosmsg but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-rospy-tutorials but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-sensor-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-std-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-std-srvs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-stereo-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-tf but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-tf2-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-trajectory-msgs but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-noetic-visualization-msgs but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354207/install-ros1-bridge-on-foxy-is-failing/) by [maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/55264/maxime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-06-05**:
In the future, mind posting the text instead of an image of text? Text is searchable, so it will help you and others find this same question again in the future.

**Comment by [maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/55264/maxime/) on 2020-06-05**:
Smart ! Will do next time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-06**:
@maxime: because there is already an answer here, I won't do it, but according to the support guidelines, we should've closed your question and you would've had to replace the screenshot with actual text.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-06-06**:
My bad I faced the exact same issue when this was posted so I replied without looking at the question closely.
@maxime I took the liberty of updating your question with the console output I had when I ran into the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install the `ros1_bridge` you need to add the ROS 1 APT repository to your sources.

You can find how to do so at https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2FUbuntu.2FSources.Setup_your_sources.list

Copying it here for a self-contained answer:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
sudo apt update
```

After that you should be able to install the ros1-bridge deb:

```
sudo apt install ros-foxy-ros1-bridge
```

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/55264/maxime/) on 2020-06-05**:
You are indeed right !